# PostgreSQL: Select one of two fields depending on which is empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, ternary-operator

Hello I have a query where I want to select the value of one of two fields depending if one is empty.

```
field1 and field2
```

I want to select them as `complete_field`

```
IF field1 is empty, then complete_field is field2
ELSE complete_field is field1
```

In php it would be done like:

```
$complete_field = $field1 == '' ? $field2 : $field1;
```

How would I do this in PostgreSQL?

I tried:

```
SELECT
(IF field1 = '' THEN field2 ELSE field1) AS complete_field
FROM
table
```

But it doesnt work.

Please help me :) Thanks

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE(field1, field2) AS the_field FROM my_table;` would work if the fields were NULL. Are they really empty strings instead of being NULL?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE .. END`, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN (field1 IS NULL OR field1 = '') THEN field2 ELSE field1 END)
FROM table;
```

Check it out at [the official docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html).

Answer (score 50):

Try [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html) with [`NULLIF`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html):

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(field1, ''), field2) AS the_field FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 9):

The ANSI SQL function Coalesce() is what you want.

```
 select Coalesce(field1,field2)
 from   table;
```

Comment: Apparently `field1` may be an empty string, in which case the OP does not want its value, but `field2`'s value instead.

Comment: Ugh. Recently converted from Oracle and I don't like this empty-string-is-not-null malarkey.